# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Sintaxis incorrecta cerca de '@VARIABE'.' c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedure, function

tengo el siguiente código el cual mando a llamar una función con un parámetro de entrada de tipo string en un formulario en donde se realiza una búsqueda por numero de identificación, pero al ejecutar me arroja el error descrito en la pregunta.

```
public static List<Buscar_Paciente_RUT> Busqueda_Paciente_RUT(String Nom_Pac)
    {
        List<Buscar_Paciente_RUT> listPR = new List<Buscar_Paciente_RUT>();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlCommand sql;
        SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter1;
        string connstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Trabajo"].ToString();
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstring))
        {
            conn.Open();
            sql = new SqlCommand("fn_Find_Paciente_RUT(@NOMPACRUT)", conn);
            Console.WriteLine(sql);
            if (conn != null)
            {
                sqlDataAdapter1 = new SqlDataAdapter();
                sql.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                //sql.Parameters.Add("@NOMPACRUT",SqlDbType.Text).Value = Nom_Pac;
                sql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NOMPACRUT", Nom_Pac);
                sqlDataAdapter1.SelectCommand = sql;
                sqlDataAdapter1.Fill(dt); <-- AQUI SE DISPARA EL ERROR
            }
            foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows)
            {
                Buscar_Paciente_RUT dsr = new Buscar_Paciente_RUT
                {
                    PAC_ID = Convert.ToInt32(r["PAC_ID"].ToString()),
                    PAC_APELLIDO = r["PAC_APELLIDO"].ToString(),
                    PAC_CODIGO = r["PAC_CODIGO"].ToString(),
                    PAC_COD_ODONT = r["PAC_COD_ODONT"].ToString(),
                    PAC_COMUNA = r["PAC_COMUNA"].ToString(),
                    PAC_CONVENIO = r["PAC_CONVENIO"].ToString(),
                    PAC_CORREO = r["PAC_CORREO"].ToString(),
                    PAC_DIRECCION = r["PAC_DIRECCION"].ToString(),
                    PAC_NOMBRE = r["PAC_NOMBRE"].ToString(),
                    PAC_OBSERVACIONES = r["PAC_OBSERVACIONES"].ToString(),
                    PAC_OTRAS_COMUNAS = r["PAC_OTRAS_COMUNAS"].ToString(),
                    PAC_PREVISIONES = r["PAC_PREVISIONES"].ToString(),
                    PAC_REPRESENTANTE = r["PAC_REPRESENTANTE"].ToString(),
                    PAC_RUT = r["PAC_RUT"].ToString(),
                    PAC_SEXO = r["PAC_SEXO"].ToString(),
                    PAC_TELEFONO = r["PAC_TELEFONO"].ToString(),
                    PAC_EDAD = Convert.ToInt32(r["PAC_EDAD"].ToString()),
                    PAC_FEC_REG = Convert.ToDateTime(r["PAC_FEC_REG"].ToString()),
                    PAC_FECHA_NAC = Convert.ToDateTime(r["PAC_FECHA_NAC"].ToString()),
                };
                listPR.Add(dsr);
            }
            return listPR;
        }
    }
```

De antemano agradezco su ayuda y colaboración.

Comment: El nombre del procedimiento es `fn_Find_Paciente_RUT` y no lleva ninguna variable. El parámetro ya lo tienes definido en un `sqlParameter`. El código debería de ser: `sql = new SqlCommand("fn_Find_Paciente_RUT", conn);` Y El tipo de comando no es command text sino stored Procedure. `sql.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;`

Comment: Creo que el problema es que estás usando una función cuando deberías de estar usando un procedimiento almacenado o consulta. Intenta agregando un `SELECT ` antes del nombre de la función.

Comment: @Javifer2 al hacer lo que me dices, me sale Error en la solicitud procedimiento 'fn_Find_Paciente_RUT'. 'fn_Find_Paciente_RUT' es un objeto función con valores de tabla.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adjunto la respuesta de como quedo el codigo finalmente y totalmente funcional.

```
public static List<Buscar_Paciente_RUT> Busqueda_Paciente_RUT(String Nom_Pac)
    {
        List<Buscar_Paciente_RUT> listPR = new List<Buscar_Paciente_RUT>();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlCommand sql;
        SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter1;
        string connstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Trabajo"].ToString();
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstring))
        {
            conn.Open();
            sql = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM dbo.fn_Find_Paciente_RUT(1,100,@NOMPACRUT)", conn);
            Console.WriteLine(sql);
            if (conn != null)
            {
                sqlDataAdapter1 = new SqlDataAdapter();
                //sql.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                //sql.Parameters.Add("@NOMPACRUT",SqlDbType.Text).Value = Nom_Pac;
                sql.Parameters.AddWithValue("NOMPACRUT", Nom_Pac);
                sqlDataAdapter1.SelectCommand = sql;
                sqlDataAdapter1.Fill(dt);
            }
            foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows)
            {
                Buscar_Paciente_RUT dsr = new Buscar_Paciente_RUT
                {
                    PAC_ID = Convert.ToInt32(r["PAC_ID"].ToString()),
                    PAC_APELLIDO = r["PAC_APELLIDO"].ToString(),
                    PAC_CODIGO = r["PAC_CODIGO"].ToString(),
                    PAC_COD_ODONT = r["PAC_COD_ODONT"].ToString(),
                    PAC_COMUNA = r["PAC_COMUNA"].ToString(),
                    PAC_CONVENIO = r["PAC_CONVENIO"].ToString(),
                    PAC_CORREO = r["PAC_CORREO"].ToString(),
                    PAC_DIRECCION = r["PAC_DIRECCION"].ToString(),
                    PAC_NOMBRE = r["PAC_NOMBRE"].ToString(),
                    PAC_OBSERVACIONES = r["PAC_OBSERVACIONES"].ToString(),
                    PAC_OTRAS_COMUNAS = r["PAC_OTRAS_COMUNAS"].ToString(),
                    PAC_PREVISIONES = r["PAC_PREVISIONES"].ToString(),
                    PAC_REPRESENTANTE = r["PAC_REPRESENTANTE"].ToString(),
                    PAC_RUT = r["PAC_RUT"].ToString(),
                    PAC_SEXO = r["PAC_SEXO"].ToString(),
                    PAC_TELEFONO = r["PAC_TELEFONO"].ToString(),
                    PAC_EDAD = Convert.ToInt32(r["PAC_EDAD"].ToString()),
                    PAC_FEC_REG = Convert.ToDateTime(r["PAC_FEC_REG"].ToString()),
                    PAC_FECHA_NAC = Convert.ToDateTime(r["PAC_FECHA_NAC"].ToString()),
                };
                listPR.Add(dsr);
            }
            return listPR;
        }
    }
```

Si existe alguna otra manera mas simple de realizar lo mismo me ayudan indicando para mejorar el código.

Gracias por su ayuda.